# Effective way to iterate through all directories in python

Tags: python, list, directory

Let's say we want the following:

directory A contains directory B, and directory B contains three directories: C_one, C_two
We want to combine lists (all named 'features') in C_one, C_Two, C_three

we want

```
from A.B import C_one, C_two, C_three 
my_list = C_one.features + C_two.features + C_three.features
```

However, this seems a bit inefficient as you manually have to specify that which ones to import

```
from A.B import C_one, C_two, C_three
```

from A.B and manually have to specify

```
C_one.features + C_two.features + C_three.features
```

Is there a way to combine this one one sitting? Like

```
my_list = []
for directory in A.B:
    my_list.extend(A.B.directory.features)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the os module to dynamically get the list of subdirectories in directory B and then import and combine the features from each subdirectory. Here's an example:

```
import os

# Assuming A.B is the path to directory B
directory_b_path = "A/B"

# Get a list of subdirectories in directory B
subdirectories = [d for d in os.listdir(directory_b_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory_b_path, d))]

# Initialize an empty list to store the combined features
my_list = []

# Iterate through each subdirectory and combine features
for subdirectory in subdirectories:
    # Construct the import statement dynamically
    import_statement = f"from A.B.{subdirectory} import features"
    exec(import_statement)
    
    # Extend the my_list with the features from the current subdirectory
    my_list.extend(features)

# Now my_list contains the combined features from all subdirectories
print(my_list)
```

Note: Using exec to dynamically execute import statements should be done cautiously, as it can introduce security risks if not handled properly. Make sure that the directory names are safe and do not contain any malicious code. If the directory names are user-input or come from an untrusted source, additional validation is recommended.

Also, this solution assumes that the features attribute exists in each of the subdirectories. Adjust the code accordingly based on the structure of your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to dynamically import modules:

```
import os
import importlib


module_list = [
    importlib.import_module(f'A.B.{entry.name}')
    for entry in os.scandir('A/B') if entry.is_dir()
]

my_list = [feature for module in module_list for feature in module.features]
```